# Test other Activity in different package declare in manifest file

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, package, android-resources

I have this issue, but I don't know how to solve this:
I have two package, for example `packageA` (there are many classes inside, for example `classA`) and `packageB` (same, there are many classes inside, for example `classB`).

In `android manifest file`, I declare `com.packageA`, so each files in `com.packageB`, I must use :

`import com.packageA.R;`.

Now, I want to test something on `classB` (`classB` is an activity), so how I can do it ?

I have one solution is rename again, `packageA` to `packageB` and vice versa. But, I think it is too handy.

Who has another solution, please tell me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to rename any of the class just call the classes along with package name as per below

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name="com.package1.ClassName"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />      


<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name="com.package2.ClassName"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```